# Reading data from a data.frame

Tags: r

I want to read data from a data fram. I have this block of code to do that, but the resault is not what I want. Could some one explain me, what is levels and how can I have only the numbers?

```
ck<-read.table("clipboard")
datalist<-ck[seq(1, nrow(ck), by = 2),]
```

and as an output, I have:

```
[1] 491 492 494 492 493 492 494 493 493 492 491 491 493 494 492 493 494 492 493 492 491 494 492 491 493 495
[27] 492 492 491 493 492 493 495 493 492 491 494 493 492 491 491 494 492 493 492 492 492 492 494 492 491 493
[53] 493 493 494 493 491 495 495 492 493 494 492 490 491 494 492 495 491 495
Levels: 1,09E+13 1,14E+13 1,24E+13 2,21E+12 490 491 492 493 494 495 7,06E+12 7,50E+11 8,03E+12
```

Comment: `read.table("clipboard" , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. I'll leave you to read the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) (N.B. you *may* want to specify `colClasses` as `"integer"` too, but not seeing all your data it is hard to say for sure).

Comment: thanks a lot, It is my answer :)

Comment: `read.table("clipboard")` is usually a bad idea.  In general, it is better to save your data to a file, then read that file.